# How to filter out sub groups in DSQUERY?

Tags: batch-file, active-directory, dsquery

In DSQUERY when finding AD objects, I want to find a DL (distribution list) or AD security group, and find all it's users (even in sub groups) and then filter out the sub groups. I have this so far

```
dsquery group -samid YourGroupName | dsget group -members -expand
```

from here https://michlstechblog.info/blog/windows-get-all-groups-a-user-is-memberof-by-dsquerydsget-recursive/

but it includes the sub groups. Is there a way I can filter it so that only the users remain? This dsquery does something like that, but I don't know how to tie it in with the above query.

```
 | dsquery * -filter "(&(objectcategory=person)(objectclass=user))"
```

Thanks

EDIT:

Lets say I have a group `YourGroupName`, which has subgroups `YourGroupNameA`, `YourGroupNameB`. Then those subgroups have some users `User1` (YourGroupNameA group), `User2` (YourGroupNameB group), `User3` (YourGroupNameB group).

The first query above gets me

```
YourGroupNameA
YourGroupNameB
User1
User2
User2
```

However I want to get it like this

```
User1
User2
User2
```

Comment: _Observation: Is there a particular reason that you've taken all of the information from another site, then asked a question to us instead of the author of that information? At the bottom of the page you linked, there's a Leave a Reply form, surely that would have been your first port of call!_

Comment: I did anyways, but don't think they will reply considering there is no other posts..

Comment: _Surely your question should have appeared on the page as a comment! hence my observation_. Can you please edit your question to include an eample of the output you're currently getting, and an example of how you'd like it once its' filtered according to your requirements? Thank you.

Comment: ok I added an example

Comment: omaga, that's not a very useful edit, how are we supposed to filter those made up strings, you've given us absolutely no definitive information on which to filter them outside of `DSQuery`. If the question remains like it is, you're asking how to use a specific command/utility, not how to use a [[tag:batch-file]], for instance. Questions about software are really best suited to Super User, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it using objectclass or object category? Posting the details of the users and groups is a bit confidential in my case. I was hoping there would be some code that can filter on the object type (i.e. user vs group). There is a way using dsquery shown above, I just don't know how to tie it in with the first part.

Comment: Maybe if I can get the intersection of the 2 dsquery?

Comment: I understand that, you cannot be expected to post sensitive information like that omega, but I'm sure that you could make minor modifications to what you've got, whilst maintaining privacy, but not completely destroying the character set, format, syntax, patterns etc. At the moment all you're effectively doing is hoping that people with a similar environment to yours and the same tools available, can use the same commands to get a similar output. Changing the output would increase your chances of getting assistance from others too.

Comment: Is using PowerShell an option? In PowerShell, there are better options than dsquery. And if PowerShell is an option, can you install [RSAT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=45520) on the computer you're running this on (so you can just use [`Get-ADGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember))? Or does it have to work without installing anything? Either way, can you describe what your input will be (just the group name, or will you have the distinguished name to start)? And what is your desired output?

Comment: I have powershell and I believe I can install Rsat.

Comment: My input is the group name which could be a security group or distribution list. Output should be just the users (expand recursively and then filter out subgroups).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install [RSAT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=45520), you can use [the AD PowerShell cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/). To get the names of each member, recusively, you can use [`Get-ADGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember) with its `-Recursive` parameter:

```
Get-ADGroupMember YourGroupName -Recursive | Select Name
```

That will not include the names of the nested groups.

To search by the group name rather than `sAMAccountName`, you can use [`Get-ADGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroup) and pipe it into `Get-ADGroupMember`:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -eq 'YourGroupName'" |
    Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive |
    Select -Expand Name
```

If you prefer to use LDAP filters (which is what it gets converted to in the background anyway), you can use the `-LDAPFilter` parameter:

```
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(name=YourGroupName)" |
    Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive |
    Select -Expand Name
```

If you need to search by the display name (what gets shown in Outlook, for example), then you can replace `name` with `displayName`. They're often the same value, but they can be different.

To present it as a JSON string, use [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json):

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -eq 'YourGroupName'" |
    Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive |
    Select -Expand Name |
    ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: @omega Yes. DLs are still just groups in AD.

Comment: For DLs, it works on SamAccountName, how can I get it to filter on name?

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to format it as an array of JSON object?

Comment: Just pipe it into [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json). But you will likely want to add the `-Expand` to `Select` so it presents the data as an array of strings rather than an array of objects. (I updated my answer to use `-Expand`)

Comment: Whats the difference between array of strings vs array of objects?

Comment: Try to pipe it into `ConvertTo-Json` with and without the `-Expand` and you'll see.